# How to Export latitude and longitude of ROI from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-8, sentinel

I want to export the latitude and longitude values as a CSV file from GEE. I tried the below code, but this code gives me round off values of the coordinates

```
var sentImage = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('NOT_VEGETATED_PERCENTAGE', 70))
.filterDate("2016-01-02", "2020-12-30")
.filterBounds(ROI);
//print(sentImage)
var first = sentImage.median().clip(ROI);
// TEST IMAGE
 
// get image projection
var proj = first.select([0]).projection()

// get coordinates image
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj)

// put each lon lat in a list
var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: rectangle,
  scale: 10,
  
})

// get lat & lon
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'));
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'));

var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(lon
                        .map(function(element){
                        return ee.Feature(null,{prop:element})}));


//print(featureCollection);

//Export.table.toDrive(ee.Element(chartArray));
Export.table.toDrive({
 collection: featureCollection,
 folder: 'Test_Folder',
description:'test_chartArray',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `reproject()` was causing some trouble so remove that. Also you don't need to recreate a feature by mapping over the lat coordinates. This should work:

```
// put each lon lat in a list
var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
   bestEffort: true,
  geometry: ROI,
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  tileScale: 16,
  scale: 10
})


print(coords, 'coords')
var feat = ee.Feature(null, coords)
print(feat, 'feat')
Export.table.toDrive(feat)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bca7e76e0027949e49f2a37f1d00d663

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run your code it gives me this error  Error: Invalid argument: 'collection' must be a FeatureCollection. (Error code: 3)

Comment: I am new to GEE, and I want to export coordinates along with dem value in the CSV file. can you help me in this regard

Comment: The problem is solved .. the issue is reprojection. thanks

Comment: The previous error probably had to do with your assets I couldn't access. Glad it worked. If you believe this answered your question you can accept it for future reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: yes, reprojection was the issue. in your code instead of a collection, feature collection should be provided, because to import data as in table, collection must be feature collection